# loading struts-config.xml from web.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts

When I'm writting

```
<init-param>
      <param-name>config</param-name>
      <param-value>WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

This tag in `web.xml` that time I was getting the error

> word config notspelled correctly

I know this is a logical name, so you can use any word, but that word 
`config` is underlined in red. Because of that, whenever I run a struts application, I mention the path in a form tag of jsp: something like `/book`. This book path is also in 
the `struts-config.xml` file.

So when I run this project, I'm getting the error

> requested resources not available(/book)

That means `struts-config.xml` is not loaded correctly. I have imported jar also.

Comment: Where did you place struts-config.xml file.

Comment: Could you show the rest of the struts servlet config in web.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<init-param>
     <param-name>config</param-name>
     <param-value>classpath:struts-config.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Copy **struts-config.xml** to **WEB-INF/classes** folder

Also you should have all struts jar files into your **WEB-INF/lib**

Comment: struts-config.xml should be in WEB-INF folder parallel to web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so it is necessary to move struts-config.xml file somewhere. 
Actually word "config" is for initialize parameter(struts-config.xml) with name config.
config with orange color(not red)underline is only for dictionary check nothing else.

So error occurs because

In your struts-config.xml has mess or misconfigured.if possible please add you struts-config.xml with this thread so we can check what actually a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside servlet action with servlet-class ActionServlet. Worked in my case, have similar problem, but I've just wanted to change folder from classes to my default.

Answer (score -1):

`<init-param> <param-name>StrutsConfig</param-name> <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value> </init-param>`